# Problem with form option selected where parameters in the url

Tags: laravel, forms, laravel-5

Hi I have problem with my multiple select search form.

The parameters are in the url 
`urlhomepage.../search?cars=1&cars=2&cars=4`

I do not know how to get parameters url in form option as selected

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="cars[]" id="select2" placeholder="">
  @foreach($names as $name)
  <option value="{{$name->id}}">{{$name->title}}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

I want to get the effect so that the form options are marked on the basis of a url query

Answer (score 0):

First you should pass variable as array as `cars[]` like below

```
urlhomepage.../search?cars[]=1&cars[]=2&cars[]=4
```

Inside php you can get cars array form query string

```
<?php
   $cars = request('cars',[]);
?>
```

And put cars value as auto selected in select

```
<select value="{{$cars}}" multiple="multiple" name="cars[]" id="select2" placeholder="">
```

Comment: I have selected - <option value="{{$name->id}}" selected >{{$name->title}}</option>
Option 'selected' when parameters is in url